# Why dynamic form element don't post after reloading with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, post, dynamic

I have a form that in this form I reload some  elements with jquery. after I reload my div element that consist on my  values, it doesn't post

```html
<form action="addquestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="qupload-target" onsubmit="qupload_start();">
  <select name="QGrade" class="input" id="QGrade" onchange="showList('getclasslist.php?Grade=',this.value,'ClassLST10')">
    <option selected="selected">----</option>
   </select>
    <div style="float: right" id='ClassLST10'>
      <select class="input" name="QClass" id="QClass" size="3" style="width: 100px">
      </select>
    </div>
  <input type="submit" name="Send" class="login-btn" />
</form>
```

after I click on first select value, second select change with my jquery codes, when I submit form then second select doesn't post.
how I can fix this problem? and what changes I must do in codes?

Comment: you should view the generated source, and post that.

Comment: Can you create a small code sample and ask the specific question?

Comment: This is because the actions associated with the elements no longer apply to the new elements created in "div reload", you need to rebind them to the new elements in your div, they now are new elements.

Comment: how can i change select option values that they remind in my form and when i click submit button they send to my addquestion.php? because now my second select doesn't send after reloading!

Answer (score 0):

i find my answer and this for that when i reload div element it go to outside of my form. because my table don't define correctly. i correct place of table and  tags and it become true.

also you can use firebug. i find it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218767/5280683)

thanks for your answers